# Sorting (with conditions) using Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting

Using Matlab, I will like to sort the following wireless sensor readings in descending order, using the received signal strength (RSS) values in Column 2. I will like to find the average of the coordinates corresponding to the three highest RSS values. Column 3 is the coordinate of each of the sensor, while Column 4 are the wireless sensors that are visible to the sensor in Column 1.

However, there is a condition that must be met. The three highest values to be selected must be visible to each other. For instance, if sensors A,D,F are selected, sensors D and F must be visible to A, sensors A and D must be visible to F, and sensors A and F must be visible D.

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3                Column 4 
                                        (Sensors that are visible to 
                                        the sensor in Column 1)
  A          -45          1,1                  B,C,D,E,H
  B          -90          1,5                  A,D,C,E,H
  C          -50          3,9                  A,B,E,H,G
  D          -54          4,2                  A,C,B,F,G
  E          -70          4,6                  C,D,H,G
  F          -57          7,2                  B,D,H,I
  G          -75          7,6                  D,B,I,E
  H          -64          6,9                  E,D,G,I
  I          -23          9,9                  H,G,F,B
```

Looking forward to any form of assistance. Grateful

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got for the first part, sorting the data in descending order:

```
data = cell(9,4); 
col1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
col2 = [-45,-90,-50,-54,-70,-57,-75,-64,-23];
col3 = [{'1,1'},{'1,5'},{'3,9'},{'4,2'},{'4,6'},{'7,2'},{'7,6'},{'6,9'},{'9,9'}];
col4 = [{'B,C,D,E,H'},{'A,D,C,E,H'},{'A,B,E,H,G'},{'A,C,B,F,G'},{'C,D,H,G'},{'B,D,H,I'},{'D,B,I,E'},{'E,D,G,I'},{'H,G,F,B'}];
for i = 1:length(data)
    data{i,1} = col1(i);
    data{i,2} = col2(i);
    data{i,3} = col3(i);
    data{i,4} = col4(i);
end

[trash idx] = sort([data{:,2}],'descend');
newdata = data(idx,:);
```

Then for the second part, this will work for finding the average of the coordinates corresponding to the three highest RSS values but without your condition that the three highest values to be selected must be visible to each other.

```
for i = 1:3
    coord = str2num(cell2mat(newdata{i,3}));
    coord_ave(i) = mean(coord);
end
```

I'll see if I can figure anything out on the condition stuff and post something if I do. Right now I think that using strfind will work to compare columns 1 and 4 to each other like below but some additional steps will be needed to find the 3 maximum matches in all of the data:

```
current_max_sens = newdata{i,1};
cell2mat(strfind(cellstr(newdata{3,4}),current_max_sens))
```

I hope this could at least give you a starting point.

Comment: I have tried to run the first section of the program but i am receiving error message; 'The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side. error in line 9.    data{i:2} = col2(i)